# In .Net Core API when I use Microsoft Identity AddSignIn instead of old solution AddAuthentication CORS doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-authentication, microsoft-identity-platform

So I am using the preview version of Microsoft.Identity.Web for Azure Authentication and it works fine.
But our front-end is React and hosted somewhere else. So we need to enable Cors for that.
But I get a Cors error as below:

Access to fetch at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/....' (redirected from 'https://localhost:44323/imrprojects/search') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

If I change the code and use old soution it's working fine!
code in startup.cs:

```
 //services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            //{
            //    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            //})
            //.AddAzureAdBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.AddSignIn(Configuration);
```

If I use services.AddAuthentication it works but when I use services.AddSignIn it's not working.

I have  services.AddCors and app.UseCors in place by the way.

Comment: I _think_ you need to use AddProtectedWebApi() or something like that to add Bearer token authentication. You seem to be adding interactive authentication.

Comment: Is that you use Azure AD to project web API?

Answer (score 0):

Thansk juunas! You are right. I think I must use AppProtectedWebAPI.

Now I get this error in frontend but I think I need to add scope or roles in App Registeration then.

Neither scope or roles claim was found in the bearer token

Comment: So that was it. I added some roles and assigned a role to myself and everything is working now.